# HTML5 video: need to find viewed time from "play" to "pause" with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I need to find the viewed time of an HTML video from when a user clicks "play", to when click "pause"; at the moment I have found only the currentTime with a code like this, but this is not what I need:

```
$("video").on('timeupdate', function(){
   console.log(this.currentTime);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On video `"play"` Store a [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) *ms* value into the element `data-start` attribute
- On video `"pause"` calculate the difference from `Date.now()` and `data-start`
- Store the cumulative *ms* result into `data-viewtime` attribute for later reference and addition.

```js
const EL_video = document.querySelector("#vid");

EL_video.addEventListener("play", () => {
  EL_video.dataset.start = Date.now();
});

EL_video.addEventListener("pause", () => {
  const diff = Date.now() - EL_video.dataset.start;
  EL_video.dataset.viewtime = (+EL_video.dataset.viewtime || 0) + diff;
  console.log(`Total view time: ${EL_video.dataset.viewtime} ms`);
});
```

```css
video {max-height: 150px;}
```

```html
<video id="vid" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ahmetaksungur/aksvideoplayer/main/videos/video-360.mp4" controls></video>
```